# React + d3 Tooltip Overlap With Legend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have created a stacked and grouped bar chart with React + d3. The first time it loads you can click on any legend and it will toggle the graph. However, once you hover over and the graph and the tooltip is displayed, then the tooltip overlaps with the legend and you cannot click on legend to toggle anymore. The attached image shows how it overlaps.

[image: image link]

The full code demo is [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-fog-8srz7?file=/src/StackedBarGraph.js)
Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` does not work in your case. But what works is setting height to `0` on `mouseout` and setting height back to `auto` on `mouseover`.

```
.on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
  tooltip.transition().duration(50).style("opacity", 1).style("height", "auto");
})

.on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
  tooltip.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0).style("height", "0%");
});
```